# * is illegal for a struct?

Tags: c, struct, pointers

I tried to compile the following code, but the compiler wouldn't doing because " * is illegal for a struct" is that true?

```
struct String {
    int length;
    int capacity;
    unsigned check;
    char ptr[0];
} String;

void main(){

    char *s;
    String *new_string = malloc(sizeof(String) + 10 + 1);

}
```

Comment: in your code `String` is an object of type `struct String`.

Comment: so how would i fix that?

Comment: In your code `String` is an object of type `struct String`. It's similar to: `int a; void main() {; a *b = malloc(sizeof *b);}`

Comment: In otherwords, the `String` at the end of the struct declaration is declaring an instance of String named String. I'm guessing you want to get rid of the trailing "String".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Either use a typedef:

```
typedef struct String {
    int length;
    int capacity;
    unsigned check;
    char ptr[0];
} String;    /* now String is a type */
```

Or explictly say `struct String`:

```
void main(){
    char *s;
    struct String *new_string = malloc(sizeof(struct String) + 10 + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 18):

As nobody seems to have mentioned this yet, let me explain what the code *you* used actually means.

What you used is a kind of shorthand notation that defines a struct *and also* creates a variable. It is equivalent to:

```
struct String {
    int length;
    int capacity;
    unsigned check;
    char ptr[0];
};
struct String String; //creates a global variable of type "struct String"
```

Later,

```
String *new_string
```

fails to compile because there is no type name by the name of "String" (only of "struct String". There is a global variable whose name is "String" but that doesn't make sense in this expression.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the `typedef`:

```
typedef struct String {
    int length;
    int capacity;
    unsigned check;
    char ptr[0];
} String;
/* String is now a type, not an object */

void main(){

    char *s;
    String *new_string = malloc(sizeof(String) + 10 + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is true. Binary `*` operator (multiplication) is only applicable to arithmetic types. In your example you declared a variable `Struct` of type `struct Struct` and then tried to multiply it by something. This just doesn't make any sense. You can't multiply struct objects. This is what the compiler is telling you.

Additionally:
1. That's `int main`, not `void main`.
2. C language doesn't support array declarations with size 0. You might want to change the array declaration inside your struct type.

Answer (score 2):

use this code:

```
struct String* new_string = malloc(sizeof(String)+10+1);
```

you can also consider [typedef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)

```
typedef struct String sString;
```

will let you use your snippet:

```
sString* mystring
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 typedef struct String_t {
        int length;
        int capacity;
        unsigned check;
        char ptr[0];
    } String;
```

Yours doesn't quite declare a type like that. More specifically, it hides your type by introducing a variable of the same name. And that gets the compiler confused... :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I now see that the original question was tagged `C` and not `C++` and someone erroneously tagged it `C++` (reverted the tagging).

---

One solution, as others mentioned, is to add a `typedef` before the `struct` declaration however since this is `C++` (according to the question's tag) and not `C` a more idiomatic and shorter way would be to just drop the trailing "String"

```
struct String {
    int length;
    int capacity;
    unsigned check;
    char ptr[0];
};
```

This is enough to introduce a type called `String` the reason your original code didn't work was that in addition to introducing a type called `String` you introduced a variable called `String` which hid the type.

Answer (score 0):

As artelius wrote earlier, your struct definition is likely not what you want. The easiest fix would be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct String {
    int length;
    int capacity;
    unsigned check;
    char ptr[0];
};

int main(){
    char *s;
    String *new_string = (String*)malloc(sizeof(String) + 10 + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

This actually compiles too when I tested with both gcc and g++. If you are really doing C++ as your tags imply, you should rather include cstdlib instead of stdlib.h or do it properly(tm) and turn your string into a class and use new.