# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation: at FileTest.main(FileTest.java:39)

Tags: java

Im getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation: at FileTest.main(FileTest.java:39) Line 39 is `public static void main(String[] args){`what am I doing wrong?

```
public class FileTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
            String inFileName = args[0];
            String outFileName = args[1];
            BufferedReader ins= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFileName));
            BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            PrintWriter outs = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFileName));

            String first = ins.readLine(); //read from file
            while(first != null){
                System.out.print("Type in a word to follow " + first + ":");
                String second = con.readLine(); //read from console
                //append and write 
                outs.println(first+ ", " + second);
                first = ins.readLine(); //read from file
            }
            ins.close();
            outs.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224201/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-error-unresolved-compilation-problems

Comment: @Ankur it appears to me that i've accepted answers to all my questions. Idk why it's still at 52%...

Comment: @user133466 [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/133466/user133466?tab=questions). The ones with green backgrounds but white text for the answer counts are questions that are answered without an accepted answer.

Comment: @Brian and  user133466, I was just going through the previous questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622323/is-illegal-for-a-struct and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598773/is-there-a-standard-function-in-c-that-would-return-the-length-of-an-array which could easily be accepted, thats why I left a comment

Comment: @Ankur I see that now :) But 52% is still middle-of-the-road. I'd be more concerned if it were below 40% or 30%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have too many braces. You can delete the last `}` character to make this code compile.

Comment: now I have a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at FileTest.main(FileTest.java:48)`

Comment: That is a Runtime exception probably caused by not passing in arguments I would guess. As youre using Eclipse, you can supply arguments in Program Arguments in your Run Configuration.

Comment: @Ankur how can i pass a command line argument? I just clicked the "play" button in Eclipse to compile...

Comment: @user133466 try this: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html

Comment: Use the "Run configurations" option. There's an "Arguments" tab with a "Program arguments" field.

Comment: @Brian I've added the argument, but now it's saying "in.txt, (The system cannot find the file specified)" but I'm sure have created a in.txt text file under the source directory ....

Comment: Put it under the project root directory, not the source directory.

Comment: Hi @Brian, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866146/java-io-filenotfoundexception-in-txt-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specifie