# java.io.FileNotFoundException: in.txt, (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: in.txt, (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at FileTest.main(FileTest.java:50)
```

Yet Im certain that I have created a in.txt file under the src, bin, and root directory. I also tried specifying the full directory in my main parameters, but still not working. Why isn't Eclipse picking it up?

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String inFileName = args[0];
            String outFileName = args[1];
            BufferedReader ins = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFileName));
            BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            PrintWriter outs = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFileName));

            String first = ins.readLine(); // read from file
            while (first != null) {
                System.out.print("Type in a word to follow " + first + ":");
                String second = con.readLine(); // read from console
                // append and write
                outs.println(first + ", " + second);
                first = ins.readLine(); // read from file
            }
            ins.close();
            outs.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to put it outside the src directory, in the project directory, IIRC.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, I have done that already, but still on luck...

Comment: How are running you Java program?  I'm seeing that the filenames are received through args param.

Comment: @HernanVelasquez running it by clicking the green "Play" button (but I have specified the parameters as in.txt and out.txt and c:\user\workspace\project\bin\in.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code and executed it with the following command-line params:

```
in.txt out.txt
```

It works with no problems at all. Check your command line.

Comment: so params should be separated by a space, not comma?

Comment: Yes, this is the command line we're talking about, as if you were entering this at the command prompt. The only separator needed (and allowed) is whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

Given the error message, I would guess that Java is looking for the file name `in.txt,`, with a trailing comma.

Comment: You shouldn't. Arguments are separated by a white space.

Comment: +1 Eagle eye... Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) out.

Comment: But you have another problem. Your exclamation mark key seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Eclipse will set the working directory to the project folder. If you have made changes to the settings, you can still find out the working directory by this simple line of code:

```
System.out.println(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath());
```

Put your text file in the folder printed, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the project directory and if that doesn't work, the bin folder

Answer (score 0):

Open your "Debug Configurations" and set, under the tab "Arguments", the Working Directory. Relative paths will be relative to the Working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project `Learning` in my eclipse and put `in.txt` file inside a source directory . I tested using the sample java file .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("a.txt");
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Output:

```
/home/bharathi/workspace/Learning/a.txt
```

It looks in a project root directory . You can put in.txt inside a project's root directory or give the path until source directory .

Answer (score 0):

There can be two problems:

1. In your console, the error shown with the ',' check -- >
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: in.txt,
   so probably JVM looks for a filename with the ','
2. The second case can be, You in.txt file is not in the right
       location. Check whether it's is the Root of the project. or the main
       path.

That would solve these types of problems.